# when I uploaded my php application using Filezilla images are missing

Tags: php

I uploaded my php application using Filezilla and when I checked it online, all of the images are missing and total site get break. I don't understand this because everything works fine offline but when I check through after publishing it online, all the images disapear. I also checked all my links and they're fine.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> Vatsal Technosoft Messanger </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/frmvalidation.js"></script>
   <link href="../Stylesheet/style.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body> 
   <?php include 'connect.php' ?>
   <?php include 'functions.php' ?>
   <?php include 'header.php' ?>

   <div id="outer" style="margin-top:0px;">
      <div class="container" style="color:#00C; z-index:1;">

        <div class="subcontainer" >
        <?php

          if(loggedin())
          {

         ?>
         <a href='' onclick='addcontact();' id='noti' style='text-  decoration:none;margin-bottom:0px;'>
         <?php
            $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $notifrnd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `frnd_req` WHERE `to` = '$my_id' ");
        if(mysql_num_rows($notifrnd))
        {
          while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($notifrnd))
      {
             $fid = $arr[1];
         $firstname = getfirstname($fid , 'firstname');
         $lastname = getlastname($fid , 'lastname');
     }
     echo "<font style='color:#FFFF00; font-size:11px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:5px;  float:left; font-weight:bold;'>You have Friend request</font>";

        }
       }
        ?>
     </a>
     <?php

      ?>

   <iframe name ='uses' src='../indexus.php' width='185' height='140' style='max-width:185px; background-color:#ccc;'>
  </iframe>

 <?php

    if(adminlogedin())
      {
         $admin_id = $_SESSION['admin_id'];
         eader('location:admindex.php');
       }

  ?>
  </div>

  </div>
     <div class="footer">
        <div class="online">
            <?php
                if(loggedin())
                {
                echo "<img src='../Images/ym1.png'>";
                }
                else
                {
                 echo "<img src='../Images/ym2.png'>";
                 }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footertext">
         <?php
               if(loggedin())
               {
                   $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                   $firstname = getfirstname($my_id , 'firstname');
                   $lastname = getlastname($my_id , 'lastname');
                   echo " $firstname  $lastname ";
               }
               else
               {
               }
     ?>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: you have kept your images in `Images` folder right?did you check wheter this folder is there or not on server?

Comment: also beware about folder name use always file and folder name in small letter. where is images shows i didn't find any image path in your code

Comment: Were the images uploaded? Are you 100% sure the links are "fine"? What are the HTTP response codes?

Comment: @ Rakesh Sharma :  yes i used small letters for my folder names and I have two or three images in that page. and other are in external css. you can find if(loggedin())
                {
                echo "<img src='../Images/ym1.png'>";
                }
                else
                {
                 echo "<img src='../Images/ym2.png'>";
                 }

Comment: @user2936213  :  yes I am uploading my project with images folder

Comment: have you checked again as @rakesh told.is your images folder named `Images` or `images` ("i" is capital or small)?

Comment: @user2936213  : yes I used 'I' for images and in my code I used same 'I' for images.  my folder is Images and i mentioned path as Images/img1.png

Comment: check for the permissions on server for this folder.